# NoSuchMethodError: void org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.mergeInOptionsFromCaps

Tags: java, docker, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been having some issues with setting up selenium tests lately. I had to upgrade my project's Java version from 11 to 17 to support Spring Boot V3, and my functional tests seem to fail with this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.mergeInOptionsFromCaps(java.lang.String, org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.merge(ChromeOptions.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.merge(ChromeOptions.java:48)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.AbstractDriverFactory.merge(AbstractDriverFactory.java:90)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.AbstractDriverFactory.createCommonCapabilities(AbstractDriverFactory.java:82)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.ChromeDriverFactory.createCapabilities(ChromeDriverFactory.java:56)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.ChromeDriverFactory.createCapabilities(ChromeDriverFactory.java:25)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:111)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:67)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CreateDriverCommand.lambda$createDriver$0(CreateDriverCommand.java:76)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.SelenideLogger.get(SelenideLogger.java:118)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CreateDriverCommand.createDriver(CreateDriverCommand.java:52)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.createDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:180)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:149)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverRunner.java:130)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.StaticDriver.getAndCheckWebDriver(StaticDriver.java:65)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver.getAndCheckWebDriver(SelenideDriver.java:220)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.Navigator.lambda$navigateTo$0(Navigator.java:72)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.SelenideLogger.run(SelenideLogger.java:105)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:70)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.Navigator.open(Navigator.java:32)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver.open(SelenideDriver.java:101)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:52)
    at com.sonatype.sab.SabFunctionalTest.testIndexHtml(SabFunctionalTest.java:19)
```

I have a feeling it is due to mismatched dependencies, but not entirely sure. This is the relevant part of the pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <selenium.version>4.8.0</selenium.version>
    <docker.image.registry></docker.image.registry>
    <docker.image.version>4.8</docker.image.version>
    <docker.image>standalone-chrome:${docker.image.version}</docker.image>
    <webdriver.chrome.driver>${project.build.directory}/chromedriver</webdriver.chrome.driver>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>${unified.artifactId}</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <!-- NOTE: this is not the executable jar since that one wont work with @SpringBootTest -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
      <version>6.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Originally, I was running selenium V4.1.1, and with that I was getting this error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/opentelemetry/sdk/metrics/exemplar/ExemplarFilter`

I thought updating selenium to 4.8 would fix it (which it did) but now I'm running into other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with removing all my selenium dependencies except the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```